# How do I escape special character to write XML using LXML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-2.7, lxml

I have the following XML with invalid characters

```
  <capability_camctrl_privilege>
  <descr>Indicate whether to support &#8220;Manage Privilege&#8221; 
  <dependent>True</dependent>
```

I read in the XML in the following way
`root = etree.fromstring("%s" % in_xml,
                              parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True))`

And save the XML which i loaded in Dictionary structure,

finally i made some modification and trying to output a new XML ,

node = etree.Element(STRING_WITH_SPECIAL_CHRACRTER)

i got the error message `All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes`

i tried to escaped the invalid strings, by import

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr
```

however it doesn't work, does anyone can help me to fix the problem?
thank you very much!

Python Version 2.7

Comment: What special/invalid characters are you trying to include exactly?

Comment: to James : the special character may be  “  , i found the function escape(),and quoteattr could not escape the sign ->  “

Comment: Okay.  The first argument to Element() is the tag name (i.e. the `descr` in `<descr>...</descr>`), which can not include a quote character.  Are you sure you're using the API as it is documented to work?

Comment: i don't put the invalid character in TAG Name. The invalid character was trying to put into TEXT . XML_NODE.text , and then throws the Exception and Error Message ! is there any function can escape any invalid characters in LXML , such as “ :&#8220; ” &#8221;

Comment: Perhaps it'd help to post a small self contained example that causes the problem?  That might make it easier for people to help.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common error message with `lxml`. The solution is to convert the string to unicode before using it with `lxml`. To do that, you'll need to know the encoding, but a guess of **UTF-8** is very often correct if you don't happen to know.

```
in_xml_unicode = unicode(in_xml, 'utf-8')
root = etree.fromstring(in_xml_unicode, parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
```